# How to execute the method until every Ajax method get data

Tags: jquery

I have a log method which need to execute until ajax method: getUserIP  get the value.
getUserIP will be run in $document.ready() method, and in its success method,it will run another ajax method called getsas method.
code like this:

```
 var userIP,sasToken,isReady;
$(document).ready(function ( ) { 
  getUserIP();
});

function getUserIP() {
    if (!userIP) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://jsonip.com?callback=?",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            jsonp: "callback",
            jsonCallback: "jsonCallBack",
            success: function (data) {
                callback(data);
                getSASEveryMinute();
            }
        });
    }
}
//Handle the response data from jsonip and SASTokenService.svc
//save them in globle varible 
function callback(data) {
    if (data.ip)
        userIP = data.ip
    else {
        sasToken = data.sasToken;
        isReady = true;
    }
}
function getSASEveryMinute() {
    url = "http://asdfasdf/TokenService.svc/json/Logs/" + userIP;
    getSAS();
    function getSAS() {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "jsonp",
            jsonp: "callback",
            jsonpCallback: "jsonCallback",
            success: function (data) {
                callback(data);

            }
        });
    }
    setInterval(function () {
        getSAS();
    }, 60000);
}


 function insertEntity(entity) {
        if (isReady) {
            entity.PartitionKey = userIP;
            insert(entity);       
        }
        else {
            setTimeout(function () { insertEntity(entity) }, 2000);
        }
```

Do we have a better way then

```
 setTimeout(function () { insertEntity(entity) }, 2000);
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Look for jQuery `when()`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: do you really intend for `getSAS` to be call ad-infinitum?  You never cancel the `setInterval` loop.

Comment: yes, I need it call every minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, separate out your AJAX calls into functions that do *nothing* except place a single AJAX request, and then `return` the `jqXHR` value:

```
function getUserIp() {
    return $.ajax(...).then(function(data) {
        return data.ip;
    });
}

function getSAS(userIp) {
     return $.ajax(...);
}
```

Note the use of `.then` to "filter" the return value from the first AJAX call so that it only returns the desired IP address, and not the whole `data` structure.

You'll then need a function that tries to get the SAS token once per minute, but doesn't "resolve" the promise until it has it:

```
function getSASRepeatedly(userIp) {
    var def = $.Deferred();

    (function loop() {
        getSAS(userIp).done(function(data) {
           if (data.sasToken) {
               def.resolve(userIp, data.sasToken);
           } 
           setTimeout(loop, 60000);  // do it again
        });
    )();

    return def.promise();
}
```

Then you can use `.then` and `.done` to chain it all together:

```
getUserIp().then(getSASRepeatedly).done(function(ip, token) {
    // do your insert here
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It seems like what I'm looking for!
I will check it first.

Comment: I've just modified this slightly so that `getSASRepeatedly` actually gets called every minute even once the first token has been returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can just put `insertEntity` into `getSAS` ajax callback:

```
function getSAS() {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp: "callback",
        jsonpCallback: "jsonCallback",
        success: function (data) {
            callback(data);
            // Get the entity, if it's not global
            insertEntity(entity);
        }
    });
}
```

An alternative is to use [when()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when) which can execute a callback when a deferred object finishes.

Comment: `.when` is normally best used to execute a callback when _multiple_ deferred objects are resolved.

Comment: Agree, but we can also pass deferred from one context to another to attach various callbacks via `when`.

Comment: but, in my case ,  if I want to run the ajax call in $(document).ready(), and want the second ajax based on the first ajax, what should I do?

Comment: You already have first step covered - call second ajax from first ajax's callback. Now you just need to call a function (that should be called once both ajax requests are done) from second ajax's callback.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use jQuerys ajaxStop() method. See http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/ for examples and documentation.